# Is it possible to set Origin Header for a iframe?

Tags: html, iframe, amazon-s3, cross-domain, cors

What is **required**

I have a HTML/CSS document that I want to load on another Webapp and modify.

Choose to use a iframe so no style parent leaks into the document to be edited.

What have **been done**

The original document is saved on S3. S3 is correctly configured for CORS support.

When a image or video tag is placed with crossorigin="anonymous" attribute. The correct origin headers are send and S3 sets Access-Control-Allow-Origin in the response header.

**Problem**

When loading a html document inside a iframe from the same S3 bucket. I don't get Access-Control-Allow-Origin in the reponse header since origin header for CORS is not set.

So S3 won't send Access-Control-Allow-Origin if it doesn't receive the correct origin header in the request.

**Solution Tried**

I am happy with a solution that works only in modern browsers. And thus have looked into 
HTML5 iframe attributes sandbox and seamless. But none of them seems to help in this case.

I have also tried loading the content through xhr2 with content type set as document and correct origin headers set. And adding this to a iframe on the page. The problem with this is the css in the head of the document doesn't get loaded.

Is there any other solution for this? I was expecting a attribute that I can set on the iframe but nothing like that in w3c spec.

Comment: Hi, how did you resolve this issue?

Comment: Was there any solutuion for this question?

Answer (score 2):

I think the solution is the one you already tried:

Load the HTML through AJAX, add it to the iframe using:

`document.open() / document.write() / document.close()`

and then rewrite all relative links to absolute links

`/css/style.css -> <origina-domain>/css/style.css`

You'll need to do this for all CSS, JS, images, etc.